# Bug in (small) bash script

Tags: linux, unix, bash, shell-script

I've been trying to find a bug in this test script, but haven't been able to so far. I'm not lazy, I promise...just new to Bash so am having a hard time catching syntax errors. I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me.

Here's the code. I call the script with the option -disableVenusBld, and it still prints "Starting build", which it shouldn't be doing right?

```
while [ $# -ne 0 ]
do
 arg="$1"
 case "$arg" in
  -disableVenusBld)
   disableVenusBld=true
   ;;
  -disableCopperBld)
   disableCopperBld=true
   ;;
  -disableTest)
   disableTest=true
   ;;
  -disableUpdate)
   disableUpdate=true
   ;;
  *)
   nothing="true"
   ;;
 esac
 shift
done

if [ "$disableVenusBld" != true ]; then
 echo "Starting build"
fi
```

Comment: I just tried what you suggest and did not get `Starting build` when I supplied the `-disableVenusBld` flag.  Can you give more information (i.e. system configuration, any output from the script when you run it, etc.)

Comment: Ugh, typo on my part. I'm stupid like that lol. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see anything wrong with your script, and it does what you expect when I run it:

```
$ bash -x 186724.sh
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ '[' '' '!=' true ']'
+ echo 'Starting build'
Starting build
$ bash -x 186724.sh -disableVenusBld
+ '[' 1 -ne 0 ']'
+ arg=-disableVenusBld
+ case "$arg" in
+ disableVenusBld=true
+ shift
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ '[' true '!=' true ']'
```

Note that I ran the script with `bash -x`. This causes all the lines beginning with `+` to be printed: you get a trace of the execution of your script. Do the same with your actual script to figure out where the problem is.